Decomposition of forms in $\operatorname{SU}(4)$-manifold
$\DeclareMathOperator\Spin{Spin}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}$Let $(X,\Omega,\omega,J)$ be a manifold with an $\SU(4)$ structure. Since $\SU(4)\subset\Spin(7)$, $X$ also has a $\Spin(7)$-structure. I want to know if there's an easy description of the subspace $\Omega^4_7$ ($\Omega^4=\Omega^4_1\oplus\Omega^4_7\oplus\Omega^4_{27}\oplus\Omega^4_{35}$, the splitting comes from the $\Spin(7)$-structure) using the $\SU(4)$ structure, i.e., in terms of $\Omega$ and $\omega$. Any idea or reference is most welcome.

I don't know the answer, but I am a bit confused by the notation. So, $X$ is a complex $4$-fold? Is $\Omega$ a holomorphic volume $4$-form on $X$? But then what is $\Omega^4$? I am just a bit confused by the notation.

Ahh, you mean $\Lambda^4$ maybe (or its complexification)? Ok, got it.

@Malkoun, yes indeed.

@SebastianGoette Doesn't this decomposition only sees the $U(4)$ structure, I got an answer here: https://acesse.dev/RSqHR, proposition 2. Maybe this is the best one can do?

Sorry, I forgot the Lefschetz part of the Hodge-Lefschetz decomposition. We have $\Lambda^{3,1}\cong\omega\Lambda^{2,0}\oplus\Lambda^{3,1}_0$ of dimension $6+10$, and $\Lambda^{2,2}\cong\omega^2\Lambda^{0,0}\oplus\omega\Lambda^{1,1}_0\oplus\Lambda^{2,2}_0$, of dimension $1+15+20$, similarly for the other parts of the Hodge decomposition. But this does not say how the $7$-dimensional $\mathrm{Spin}(7)$ recombines from the $SU(4)$ representations above.
